# How to add dropout layer in between stacked LSTM cells in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I can create an RNN network with two layered LSTMs as follows:

```
lstm_cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(50)
lstm_cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(100)
lstm_net = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell1, lstm_cell2])
```

But now I also want to include dropout layer after each lstm cell.
Something like,

```
tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([tf.nn.dropout(lstm_cell1, 0.8), tf.nn.dropout(lstm_cell2, 0.8)])
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I believe you can do something like tf.nn.dropout( [lstm_cell1, lstm_cell2], .8) If you want to drop corresponding rows.

Comment: Nope. This is not working. Probably because `lstm_cell1` or `lstm_cell2` is not a tensor.

Answer (score 6):

```
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)    
lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell,input_keep_prob=keep_prob, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
lstm_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout]* 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are my codes for stacked LSTM dropout.
The answer of Mashood Tanveer is good enough, but I would like to add that for MultiRNNCell, you had better not to use `[cell]*num_layer`. This is because `[cell]*num_layer` will stack one LSTM instance into a list, which may cause dimension unmatched. Unless you do know what dimension it will output, I suggest you use codes like this.

```
[tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size) for _ in range(num_layers)]

fw_lstms = []
for _ in range(num_layers):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size) 
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=1-drop_prob)
    fw_lstms.append(cell)

bw_lstms = []
for _ in range(num_layers):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size) 
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=1-drop_prob, 
                                         input_keep_prob=1-drop_prob)
    bw_lstms.append(cell)    
#bw_lstms = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size) for _ in range(num_layers)]

fw_init_state_ls = [lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32) for lstm in fw_lstms]
bw_init_state_ls = [lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32) for lstm in bw_lstms]

outputs, final_states_fw, final_states_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cells_fw = fw_lstms, cells_bw = bw_lstms,
   inputs = inputs,
   initial_states_fw = fw_init_state_ls, 
   initial_states_bw = bw_init_state_ls)
bi_final_state = tf.concat([final_states_fw[-1][1], final_states_bw[-1][1]], 1)
```